# Dialog Fragment width and height ignored

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

How do I set the width and height of a dialog fragment?  Everything I've read says to override the OnStart method like this:

```
    public override void OnStart()
    {
        if (Dialog == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        int dialogWidth = 300;
        int dialogHeight = 75;
        Dialog.Window.SetLayout(dialogWidth, dialogHeight);
    }
```

When I do this, the app crashes, I'm unable to trap the error as apparently it fails outside the code I'm writing.  Without this override the dialog appears and operates as expected.

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    android:minWidth="300dp" 
    android:minHeight="75dp">
    <TextView
        android:text="Select section."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/my_spinner" />
    <Button
        android:text="Ok"
        android:layout_width="200px"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="34.5dp"
        android:id="@+id/button_ok" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Apparently the `android:minWidth` and `android:minHeight` settings are ignored as all I get is a tiny dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better you define sizes in `dimens.xml` under `values` folder:

```
<resources>
    ...
    <dimen name="dialog_min_width">300dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="dialog_min_height">75dp</dimen>
    ...
</resources>
```

You can update `onResume()` method of your `DialogFragment` as follows and try:

```
public void onResume() {
    int width = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dialog_min_width);
    int height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dialog_min_height);        
    getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: I converted your code from java to c# and added it to your answer.  This does work, even though I don't understand why this works in `OnResume` and not `OnStart`.

Sidenote:  I never saw any advantage to storing a value in an external file and then retreiving it for use later.  I guess I'm a little old school.  Lol ...

Comment: @PrescottChartier: I voted to reject your edit, but I do appreciate it. The author chose to provide a Java answer, rightly or wrongly, and it can stand on its own merits. In the meantime you can write your own answer and if you want credit Mehmed's answer.

Comment: Sorry about providing solution in Java, but I know it can be ported to Xamarin. Besides it is a convention, I used dimensions file to provide sizes in dp and to get sizes in pixel using `getDimensionPixelSize()` to avoid manual calculation.

Answer (score 1):

The c# equivalent of Mehmed's code:

```
    public override void OnResume()
    {
        int width = 300; 
        int height = 75; 
        base.OnResume();
    }
```

I have found that a lot of the code posted on Stack Overflow where Xamarin is concerned is java code, I use c# (Visual Studio 2017) and know absolutely nothing about java and find it difficult to convert to c#, frustratingly so.  When I see java code in an answer, I usually just skip right over it.  But seeing as how I asked the question and Mehmed was kind enough to provide a working solution, I felt compelled to post a c# conversion.

You'll note that I opted not to place the values in `dimens.xml`, I'm not a fan of storing values in an "external to the code file" and then retrieving them in code, tends to make debugging that much more difficult at times.  All that happens when you do that is the compiler replaces the line of code with the value in the generated obj file, sooooo .. why do that?

Given that these values will never change, I saw no point in putting them in `dimens.xml`, by all means convince me otherwise!